# Microsoft Edge Browser Extension ajax for CORS request Origin Header not sent

Tags: javascript, cors, microsoft-edge, browser-extension

I am creating browser extension for Firefox, Chrome and Edge. I have been able to get my extension working in Firefox and Chrome but stuck with an issue on Edge.

When my extension loads it makes ajax GET call and fetches some initialization data.
Firefox sends `Origin` header when I am making the ajax call, which helps me set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` accordingly.

With Edge there is no `Origin` header going out with request and my check fails resulting in no response header being set and call fails with error as.

> SEC7120: [CORS] The origin
>   'ms-browser-extension://Manager_F14DC7EC297D4EDABB8E56840AE117D6' did
>   not find
>   'ms-browser-extension://Manager_F14DC7EC297D4EDABB8E56840AE117D6' in
>   the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin 
>   resource at 'https://example.com/api/i18n?_=1552907931096'.

Am I missing some thing here, manifest.json should contain some instruction specific to Edge.
*Microsoft Edge version is 42.17134.1.0*

Above scenario is happening during development, I am accessing the extension loaded from file system.

Comment: Have you ever tried to add the "Acess-Control-Allow-Origin" manually? Can you post related code about the Ajax method?Also, you could try to use the Post method to get the data.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I do not control the server, it is developed by another team, I cannot change anything related to Header or change the call to POST, any change will go through team approval process. Ajax call is simple jQuery API which is developed by same team. My task is to use their ready code as much as possible to develop extension.

Comment: According to the error message, the origin is strange, from [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), we can see that the origin is your website url. I suggest you could check the request header in Chrome, and check whether they are the website url. Besides, I suggest you could also try to directly access the resource from a web site on the Edge browser, instead of via the Edge Extension (by using this method to check whether the issue is related to the Edge extension).

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? I’m running into it myself...

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest.json,

put all the relevant URLS into the "permissions" section.

```
"permissions" : [
  "https://my-initialization-data.com/data.whatever"
]
```